# Using objects with python error

Tags: python

Hey guys am new to python development..The code which i have made

```
class Employee:
   def __init__(self, num, num1):
       self.num = num
       self.num1 = num1

   def displayCount(self,x,y):
       d = x.self.num
       p = y.self.num1
       c = d + p
       print c
```

When I call the function like

```
emp1 = Employee(3, 2000)
emp1.displayCount(3, 2)
```

It gives me error like `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'self'`.I know the error is with `x.self.num`.Why this can be done with python ??..

Hope you guys can help me out ..thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `x.self.num`?

Comment: @ZenOfPython i have seen a code like doing with x.self.num ..can it be done in python ??..if it can be done like that please post an answer showing an example

Comment: Where is that code? And why are you using `x.self.num`? Is it to update `self.num`?

Comment: Your question is unclear, because your definition of `displayCount` is cryptic. Are the `x` and `y` you pass to `displayCount` of type `Employee` or are they meant to be some other type?

Comment: @AlexReynolds i just want to know how can i add like self.onevaribale.anothervaribale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attribute of the class is an instance of an other class it could look like this.

```
class Location:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loc = Location()

    def set_coordinates(self, x_pos, y_pos):
        self.loc.x = x_pos
        self.loc.y = y_pos

p = Person()
p.set_coordinates(23, 42)
print(p.loc.x)
```

`set_coordinates` accesses `self.loc`. This is an instance of `Location`and so we can go further in the hierarchy and access `self.loc.x`.

After a lot of discussion in the comments I'll show some real bad code that shows how something like `variable.self.anothervar` is possible.

```
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar:
    def __init__(this):
        this.self = Foo()
        this.self.value = 23

class Baz:
    def print_value(this, x):
        print(x.self.value)

baz = Baz()
baz.print_value(Bar())
```

As you can see, there is nothing special about `self`. [The usage of `self` is just a naming convention](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks).

Answer (score 3):

I assume that with your `x.self.num` you are trying to update `self.num`. If you are not, please specify your error in your question.

To fix the above, you can just reassign using `self.num = x`:

```
class Employee:

   def __init__(self, num, num1):
       self.num = num
       self.num1 = num1




   def displayCount(self,x,y):
       self.num = x
       self.num1 = y
       c = self.num+self.num1
       print c
```

Which runs as:

```
>>> emp1 = Employee(3, 2000)
>>> emp1.displayCount(3,2)
5
>>>
```

Comment: no no ..i know how to do this ..but my question is can we add a third varibale like x.self.num ??

Comment: @user3805325 What do you think `x.self` and `self.x` mean?

Comment: suppose its like self.name = "somename" ..i want to do like self.name.x = "somename" ..can this be done in python ??

Comment: Yes it can be done. But I don't get what you **really** want to do. You don't understand object oriented programming yet and try to do things that are ... strange.

Comment: @Matthias please post an example on how to do it ..it would be helpful ..i just want to know in which case we want to add like self.x.anothervariable ..

Comment: @user3805325: Please check my answer and add any questions if you still have them.